# Spark scala project integration with java project

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a Java project which is a web service which is built on maven . I want to include my spark application which is built on maven in the existing java project. But i should get two different builds each for java and scala project. Is it possible?
Should i make any changes in POM.xml?

Comment: Perhaps this answer can assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720392/scala-and-java-in-same-project

Comment: I've checked that already. That's not related to my issue